# JSF/PrimeFaces selectOneMenu change url parameter and redirect

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, navigation, selectonemenu

I'm using JSF2 and PrimeFaces. How can I write selectOneMenu that would invoke JSF navigation to redirect user to the same page but with diferent parameters when he change option in menu?
I only need to change color.

From url:

```
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="vehicle" value="#{myViewController.vehicle}"/>
        <f:viewParam name="vehicle" value="#{myViewController.color}"/>
    </f:metadata>
```

MyView.xhtml: (no work)

```
    <h:form id="selectOneMenuEdition">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="selectOneMenuHeader"
                     value="#{selectOneMenuHeader.outcome}" >
        <f:selectItem itemValue="viewVehicles.xhtml?vehicle=#{myViewController.vehicle}&amp;color=red" itemLabel="Vehicle red " />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="viewVehicles.xhtml?vehicle=#{myViewController.vehicle}&amp;color=blue" itemLabel="Vehicle blue" />
        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{selectOneMenuHeader.navigate}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>
```

ManagedBean:

```
private String outcome;

public void navigate() throws IOException {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(outcome);
}
```

Comment: Where you have `outcome`, do you mean a JSF navigation outcome? Or a URL?

Comment: mmm... yes, maybe the example is wrong. I do not know what is the correct way to do this

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question: the `outcome` variable; is it a jsf navigation outcome or a full URL?

Comment: Yes, is a full url in this case, but I think that is not the best option.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your idea in principle, but you're going about it in a clumsy way. Save only the colour to the backing bean and build the URL in the `navigate` method(as against the acrobatics you're trying to perform in the view currently)

Answer (score 3):

Your `<p:selectOneMenu>` is bound to `selectOneMenuHeader.outcome`, so you just need to get its value in your bean.

Then you can create your own URL to redirect the user with the desired parameters.

Example (bean) :

```
public void navigate() throws IOException {
    String url = "yourPage.jsf?color=" + outcome;
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(url);
}
```

A second solution would be to add a javascript onchange event to redirect the user by taking the current selected option.

Example (vanilla JS) :

```
onchange="document.location.href='yourPage' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"
```